# select rows that doesn´t have a value in one column, and have the same ID

Tags: sql

I have this table: And I would like to get the IDs, that don´t have the language english.

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID | LANGUAGE | NAME  |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  | english  | james |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  | french   | john  |
+----+----------+-------+
| 2  | french   | ted   |
+----+----------+-------+
| 3  | german   | tom   |
+----+----------+-------+
| 3  | english  | james |
+----+----------+-------+
| 4  | spanish  | lucy  |
+----+----------+-------+
| 4  | german   | Bud   |
+----+----------+-------+
```

The output should be something like:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID | LANGUAGE | NAME  |
+----+----------+-------+
| 2  | french   | ted   |
+----+----------+-------+
| 4  | spanish  | lucy  |
+----+----------+-------+
| 4  | german   | Bud   |
+----+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and language = 'english'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The subquery builds a list of the id fields of all records where the language is English.

Using that, we find all records in the table which have id fields that are not in that list. So those are the records for ids where there is no English entry.

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE table.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE language='english');
```

Comment: I'd be happy to. When I was in college at least I'd get paid in beer for doing my friends' programming assignments.